# Swift: Create table of results from SwiftyJson Results

Tags: ios, json, uitableview, swift, swifty-json

I have been playing around with Swift as I'm new to iOS Development and really enjoying getting to know the language. Recently I have started to look at installing third party plugins etc and I found one called SwiftyJson (https://github.com/SwiftyJSON/SwiftyJSON) I have managed to get it to work using this script:

```
request(.GET, url, parameters: parameters)
        .responseJSON { (req, res, json, error) in
            if(error != nil) {
                NSLog("Error: \(error)")

                println(req)
                println(res)
            }
            else {
                NSLog("Success: \(url)")
                var json = JSON(json!)
                println(json)
            }
    }
```

I would like to know two things: 1) Is it possible to get the list of results from the JSON provided into a UITableView like so:

```
Item 1
----------------------------
Item 2
----------------------------
```

Etc.. and 2) How would I do that?

Edit: Json

Sorry about image - I couldn't copy it because of a stupid chrome extension I have:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible, though you aren't really using the important features of SwiftyJSON in this code sample.  The most straightforward way would be to create the tableview the same as you would for anything, likely using an array as your datasource.  Once you've received your JSON you still need to parse it and create the objects for your array.  Perhaps if you included a snippet of the JSON, it would be easier to help.

Comment: added for ya - sorry it is an image.